# Gradle: Run of a single test gives an error: Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException property '$1' as it is a directory

Tags: gradle, allure

When I try to run a single test in commandline like this:

```
gradle test --tests *MatchfichePageTest
```

I get the following error:

```html
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':test'.
> Cannot write to file '/Users/macbookprobartvr/Documents/workspace/aem-site-sporza-tests/build/allure-results' specified for property '$1' as it is a directory.
```

Full stacktrace: I cannot post because stackoverflow is complaining that there is to much code ...

Does someone know what the problem is?

Gradle version 5.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `build/allure-results` folder before running the test.

`rm -rf /Users/macbookprobartvr/Documents/workspace/aem-site-sporza-tests/build/allure-results`

now run the test, it should work now.